# Error when building Java project in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I downloaded a Java project from GitHub and trying to use Maven to build it.
I use the command *mvn clean package* on Windows 7.

I get the following error:

```
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
 3.2:compile (default-compile) on project force-wsc: Compilation failure
 [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in:
 [ERROR] C:\jdk1_8_25\..\lib\tools.jar
 [ERROR] Please ensure you are using JDK 1.4 or above and
 [ERROR] not a JRE (the com.sun.tools.javac.Main class is required).
 [ERROR] In most cases you can change the location of your Java
 [ERROR] installation by setting the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

As you can see in the error message, I AM pointing to a JDK.
My JAVA_HOME is set to C:\jdk1_8_25

When I run java -version, I get:

```
 java version "1.8.0_25"
 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)
```

There are my posts about this error but they all were pointing to a JRE and not a JKD. Mine is already pointing to a JDK so I'm not sure what is wrong here.

Comment: What is the output of java -version??

Comment: java version "1.8.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_25-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.25-b02, mixed mode)

Comment: I still believe its a classpath problem, rename your jdk folder to something easy...sometimes it helps..like just jdk....setClasspath again, check by compiling a small helloworld program, then post results.

Comment: Are you running the command with eclipse or by console?

Comment: He says he ran mvn clean, I am presuming he has maven in his classpath and running it in commandLine.

Comment: I changed it to JDK only and tried, same error: [ERROR] Unable to locate the Javac Compiler in: [ERROR] C:\jdk\..\lib\tools.jar

Comment: Did you included JAVA_HOME in the path this way?? %JAVA_HOME%\bin?

Comment: No, I included the explicit path, JAVA_HOME is set to C:\jdk

Comment: I'm also using the console, not Eclipse

Comment: Try making that change in the path variable

Comment: I changed it to %JAVA_HOME%\bin in the path and I still get the same error. Do you think it might be the new JDK version?

Comment: @JJCoolJ Did you close and reopen the command line after changing the path? If you didn't, do it, it's required if you want windows to reload environment variables

Comment: Yes I always did close and reopen the command line

Comment: What is the output when you run javac at the cmd??

Comment: javac gives me a list of options, one of them is -version. If I run javac -version I get 1.8.0_25

Comment: It's a compatibility issue between Apache Maven 3.2.3 and JDK8, I downloaded JDK6 and pointed my JAVA_HOME to it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's a compatibility issue between Apache Maven 3.2.3 and JDK8, I downloaded JDK6 and pointed my JAVA_HOME to it and it worked.